# Ubuntu 16.04 - battery charging icon showing charging when on battery

Tags: 16.04, battery, macbook

My battery icon in Ubuntu 16.04 is getting confused!

When the laptop is on battery power, it shows the battery as "Charging" but the battery is actually discharging:

[image]

When the laptop is on mains power, it shows the battery as "Discharging" but the battery is actually charging:

[image]

Restarting the laptop fixes this temporarily until I unplug and plug the charger in again. The laptop is a MacBook Air mid-2011.

Comment: facing the same issue in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS